# Image segmentation training set labeling

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, deep-learning, pytorch

I am new to pytorch and Deep learning. I am trying to do image segmentation. 
But , I am stuck at how to label training set images.

Can anyone please help me ?

This is one of my training image

[image]

I have two kinds of plants here - one is weed and another one is a good crop. I need to label them.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this ?

I am going to use deep neural network models ( like `ResNet` ) on the labelled data.

Answer (score 0):

There is discussions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/computervision/comments/5jxhtc/image_segmentation_labelling_tool/) about segmentation tools for image labeling. You may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try with https://oclavi.com which is a web-based object annotation tool